# NSwag C# client generater ignores Enum attribute

Tags: nswag, obfuscar

I have an enum which is decorated with an attribute as below, but the generated client by Nswag does not has the attribute as expected. Is there a way to configure that the attribute is present in the generated client.

```
[Obfuscation(Exclude = true, ApplyToMembers = true)]
public enum Colour
{
  Red,
  Green,
  Yellow
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting as output? JS, TS, C# client?

Comment: I'm generating a C# client.